# On Gnome, is it possible to tile windows vertically?

Tags: gnome, wayland, window-management

[The Gnome documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-windows-tiled.html.en) only refers to horizontal tiling — two windows side-by-side, each taking half of the screen space. A four-window setup could make a ≥40'' display significantly more viable for generic computer work.

Suggesting manually dragging and adjusting from the window edges (with the mouse cursor) isn't an answer. Please also note that the question is about Wayland.

Answer (score 1):

On vanilla GNOME 4X this isn't implemented. But good extensions exist for this exact purpose:

- [Tactile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4548/tactile/) is a very interesting approach, and works for me fairly well.
- [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/) is also nice.
- [Tiling Assistant](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3733/tiling-assistant/) allows to tile two windows much quicker, although not exactly a reply to your question.